# VBA: call Forms in sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have a big problem with getting called a UserForm from a sub.

This is a part of my code:

```
Sub TestForArray(ObjectName,FormName As String)       

Forms(FormName).Controls(ObjectName).List = NewArr

End sub
```

when I call this sub in a Private Sub, like this

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Call TestForArray("Form1", "ComboBox1")

End Sub
```

i get the error; "Sub or Function not defined" and higlights the word **Forms**

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error occurs because there is no Forms collection. There is only a UserForms collection but this cannot be used with names of userforms only with their index numbers. What is the goal? While initializing one Userform setting the List of a ComboBox in another Userform? Why? Why not use the _Initialize event of this other Userform to initialize it?

Comment: @AxelRichter thanks for your reply.

because i have a lot of different UserForms where there is located some ComboBoxes. It would be nice to have the opportunity to just call this function to populate the comboboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to have one Sub that can be called from different UserForms to initialize the UserForm's Controls, you can give the UserForm itself as a parameter.

Example:

```
Sub TestForArray(oForm As UserForm, sObjectName As String)
  aNewArr = [{1,2,3,4,5,6}]
  oForm.Controls(sObjectName).List = aNewArr
End Sub
```

and:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Call TestForArray(Me, "ComboBox1")
End Sub
```

Greetings

Axel